# nginx hls not live after pause

Tags: nginx, streaming, live, http-live-streaming, pause

I have a nginx running and I try to stream HLS. It all works fine but when I pause a stream and want to resume later on, this stream is not live anymore. It starts where it paused.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Post the nginx conf

Comment: http://hastebin.com/opevuvibul.coffeescript

Comment: `hls_playlist_length` is not set and defaults to 30 seconds. How long have you waited before resuming the stream?

Comment: A few seconds. Around 10 I think

Comment: then you were still in the playable window so it was able to resume from where it was paused. You either lower the playlist length or find a way to control the player to reload the playlist.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when playing with live hls. I could manage this issue listening the events trigged by the html5 video tag, so I did this:

```
    var restart = false;
    var player = document.querySelector('#videotag_id');

    player.on('play',function(){
        if (restart) {
            restart = false;
            player.src('');
            player.src({
                    'type':'application/x-mpegURL',
                    'src':'http(s)://path.to/your-stream.m3u8'
            });
            player.load();
            player.play();
        }
    });

    player.on('pause',function(){ restart = true; });
```

I hope it will help you!